# How to run a time consuming function in kotlin without blocking the Javascript and the main thread

Tags: java, android, kotlin, asynchronous

Hi I am having a solution which is implemented with Webview and android, where the communication takes place through the Javascript interface. So how to run some time consuming tasks in when the Javascript interface but without blocking the UI and the JS thread. For example,

```
class JavascriptInterface () {

  fun test(): String {
     val response = // perform some asynchronous task
     return response.toString()
  }
}
```

So in the Javascript end they could possible call the method as

`var response = await JavascriptInterface.test()`

How to achieve this behavior? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work or not, but look into using a `Handler` to run the code off of the main thread.